# NoSQL databases that officially support MonoTouch

Tags: c#-4.0, xamarin.ios, nosql

I am having trouble finding a NoSQL databases that officially support MonoTouch via a local DB on the device. If their are, could someone provide a list of them here.

Comment: CouchDB and here is a site that can help: http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/couchdb-http-api-and-mono

Comment: CouchDB doesn't officially support MonoTouch. Also that link shows it working only with Mono and via HTTP. I am looking for a local NoSQL DB that has MonoTouch support. Trust me I went to all the popular NoSQL DB's sites, and Googled my fingers off and I couldn't find any.

Comment: I know exactly how you feel. I got lost in facebook app development and wanted to jump out of a window.  Well, if a solution doesn't present itself you may have to either go rogue bleeding edge or reverse and simplify things.  Just the mention NoSQL makes me think you are dealing with transaction volume. In any case, thanks for going easy, some people would have neg'd me for attempting to help.

Comment: @FrankTudor Well poupou found two commercial ones that may work out, and if not would have found an open source one that seemed mostly Mono complant and worked it to be MonoTouch if compatible if needed.  BTW, You made it a comment not an answer so seemed like you where just trying to be helpful knowing that it doesn't answer the question exactly. It can be harsh on SO though but don't take it personally its how the system works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://nosql-database.org/ there's [siaqodb](http://siaqodb.com/). Note that others might support MonoTouch without being mentioned in that site.

**Edit**: a few more clicks shows that [HSS Database](http://highspeed-solutions.net/hssdb) (from the same list) also supports MonoTouch.

You might also want to look at which ones support iOS (e.g. with Objective C) and see if bindings are available (or write your own).

Comment: Thanks @poupou!! Did some quick research into those, and both are commercial, HSS is in Scottsdale, AZ, while SIAQODB is in Romania. HSS has some limitations that SIAQODB doesn't have. Overall on the surface SIAQODB seems the better of the two. Finally the cost for HSS is only $20/developer for all platforms, while SIAQODB is $186/developer/platform.  So I will play with their trials and see which will work best for my needs.

Comment: @RodneyFoley please report your findings, I'm curious about them! It may be better suited for the forums @ http://forums.xamarin.com/categories/ios than on SO :-)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look on [Couchbase Lite](http://components.xamarin.com/view/couchbase-lite-net) xamarin's component

Answer (score 2):

[RavenDB](http://www.ravendb.net) supports an embedded mode, and can run on Mono using the "Munin" storage engine option.

Although, there has been talk in the user group lately about dropping Munin, and it's not usually recommended for production, so it may not be a viable option.

I've not heard of someone using it with MonoTouch specifically, but there are some running it on Mono.  If you try it, please update comments here with your findings.  Thanks.

Comment: yeah I am aware of RavenDB's embedded mode and is where I would start if I couldn't find something that officially supports MonoTouhch. As my preference would be RavenDB, CouchDB, or MongoDB with RavenDB embedded having the most possibilities. If I try RavenDB and get it working I will post this in Xamarin's forums as poupou suggests.

Comment: Okay RavenDB Embedded can't work on MonoTouch because it use dynamics which are not supported on MonoTouch. Sigh.

Comment: Thanks for trying! :)  It may be awhile before there is any progress on Mono support without Munin. [See Here](https://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/7c1d98a5e066e709).  Even then, I don't think it would eliminate dynamics.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but still relevant:

I'm the author of MarcelloDB, and I just released version 0.3.0 on [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MarcelloDB/).

[MarcelloDB](https://github.com/markmeeus/MarcelloDB) is a document DB, built specifically for mobile apps (light-weight, low memory usage) and supports Xamarin Android and iOS as well as the windows platform.

I still have some features I want to add before reaching v1, but the file format and existing api are allready quite stable.