# Using embedded RavenDB cross-platform - .NET/Mono/MonoTouch/MonoDroid?

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, nosql, xamarin.android, ravendb

How can i use embedded [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/) on all major .NET platforms (.NET >= 4.0, Mono, MonoTouch, Mono for Android, [WinRT, MonoGame, etc]).

It it planned to support the embedded version cross-platform official in the future? If yes: when?

Answer (score 6):

- RavenDB runs on .NET >= 4
- You can run it on Mono.
- The client will run on MonoTouch, Mono for Android, WinRT & MonoTouch

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i need the embedded version. Is this supported too?

Comment: Embedded is not supported on monotouch.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14074152